# Multiple ul tags in columns within single channel entry tag

Tags: ee2, channel-entries, list

Trying to see if there is a way natively in EE (2.7.3) not just to switch classes within a ul but to have multiple instances of ul tags within one channel entry without using add-ons like switch?

```
<ul class="sub">
<li>A</li>
<li>B</li>
<li>C</li>
</ul>

<ul class="sub">
<li>D</li>
<li>E</li>
<li>F</li>
</ul>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Now that ExpressionEngine includes a [**modulus operator**](http://ellislab.com/blog/entry/the-modulus-operator) (as of 2.7.1), you can also use that instead of `switch` if you prefer.

Here are a couple of examples that both accomplish the same result.

**Using modulus to conditionally output *all* opening and closing html tags:**

```
{exp:channel:entries channel="news"}

    {if count % 3 == 1}
        <ul class="sub">                
    {/if}

    <li>{title}</li>

    {if count % 3 == 0 OR count == total_results}
        </ul>
    {/if}

{/exp:channel:entries}
```

...OR....

Put the first opening tag and the final closing tag *outside* of `channel:entries` and **use modulus only for conditional closing and re-opening of blocks of html:**

```
<ul class="sub">                
    {exp:channel:entries channel="news"}

        <li>{title}</li>

        {if count % 3 == 0}
            </ul>
            <ul class="sub">
        {/if}

    {/exp:channel:entries}
</ul>
```

Either of these examples will work and will always ensure that you have proper tag closure. It's just a matter of preference.

[EE Documentation on Modulus Operator](http://ellislab.com/expressionengine/user-guide/templates/globals/conditionals.html#modulus-operator)

Comment: Thank you. We deal with display issues showing columns and rows all the time and with the modulus operator this looks like it'll be much easier.

Comment: You're welcome. I was happy EllisLab added modulus, as it's a much cleaner way to handle conditional html output. Feel free to change which answer you accept. ;)

Answer (score 2):

The switch variable takes html as well. In case of your example:

```
{switch='<ul class="sub">||'}
<li>{title}</li>
{switch='||</ul>'}
```